# 2D array of object in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, oop

I have a problem with assign object 2d `[5][5]` array to object.

This is my array definition

```
class PrintRectangle : public QWidget
{

public:
    bool clicked[5][5] = {};
    teacher *tech;
    perceptron *p;

};
```

And fragment `perceptron` class

```
class perceptron
{
public:
    perceptron& operator=(const perceptron&);
};
```

When I try to assign object to my `perceptron *p`

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    tech = new teacher(clicked);

    *p = new perceptron[5][5];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
        {
            p[i][j] = new perceptron();
            p[i][j].randweight();
        }
    }

    double learnConst = 0.1;
    tech->learnPerceptrons(p);
}
```

I get an error

```
    E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:10: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'perceptron' and 'perceptron (*)[5]')
         *p = new perceptron[5][5];
            ^

E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:16: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'perceptron' and 'int')
             p[i][j] = new perceptron();
                 ^
```

I have only

```
perceptron& perceptron::operator=(const perceptron&){

    return * this;
}
```

In my perceptron class. How can I correct this? I don't cleary understend pointers.

Comment: `*p = new perceptron[5][5]` - this does not initialise a 2D array, the allocation must be done somehow else.

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*p = new perceptron[5][5];
```

is wrong for the following reasons.

1. Type mismatch.

   Type of `*p` is `perceptron`.
   Type of `new perceptron[5][5];` is `perception (*)[5]`.

   There is no conversion from `perception (*)[5]` to `perceptron`.
2. Dereferencing `p`.

   Dereferencng `p`, i.e. `*p` is going to be valid at run time only after you have allocated memory for `p`.

---

**Solution:**

You can fix your memory allocation and type mismatch problems but I strongly recommend using containers from the standard library.

```
class PrintRectangle : public QWidget
{
  public:

    std::vector<teacher> tech;               // 1D array
    std::vector<std::vector<perceptron>> p;  // 2D array.
};
```

You can initialize them in the constructor with:

```
PrintRectangle::PrintRectangle(QWidget *parent) :
   QWidget(parent),
   tech(clicked),
   p(5, std::vector<perceptron>(5))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how can I change my for loop for this?

Comment: @lukassz, you can access `tech` like you would access a 1D array and `p` like a 2D array. Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector to get started with using `std::vector`.

Comment: Ok, why this is the better way?

Comment: @lukassz, it removes the complexity of managing dynamically allocated memory from your code. That's already taken care of by the implementors of the standard library.

Comment: Ok. I assign to `tech` only one element `tech = new teacher(clicked);` it's good to make `tech` vector?

Comment: @lukassz, I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Ok, when I use your constructor I get an error `E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:12: error: cannot convert 'bool (*)[5]' to 'teacher*' in initialization
     p(std::vector<perceptron>(5), 5)
                                    ^`

Comment: `clicked` is a field in `PrintRectangle` class `bool clicked[5][5] = {};`

Comment: @lukassz, now you are bringing up issues that are not mentioned in the original post. That's why we emphasize posting a [mcve].

Comment: Yes but your code It's not working `E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:11: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<perceptron> >::vector(std::vector<perceptron>, int)'
     p(std::vector<perceptron>(5), 5)
                                    ^`

Comment: @lukassz, that was a mistake on my part. It's fixed now.

Comment: Ok, it works thanks. Now I sould put `new perceptron();` into vector in loop?

Comment: Or I must make `operator=` but I get `E:\Sieci Neuronowe\Perceptron\printrectangle.cpp:24: błąd: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<perceptron> >::value_type {aka perceptron}' and 'perceptron*')
             p[i][j] = new perceptron;
                     ^`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128885/discussion-between-lukassz-and-r-sahu).